# Background-color wordless spans

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to do something like a `background-color` without any text in stylus.

```css
span {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
}
span.red {
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<span class="red"></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `display: inline-block;` also:

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/cu9ap5rg/)

Comment: Thanks! I was totaly stumped